# Python daemon process memory footprint

Tags: python, memory-management, process

I have a daemon process which runs functions from different modules in a infinite loop.
If I were to run these modules separately, they would acquire some memory and then free it up when exiting.
But since this is a daemon process the memory used by function will not be freed up as the process is running forever and with every function executed inside the memory used by the daemon process grows which makes it look like the daemon is consuming too much of memory.

Is there a way the memory used by the function can be cleared or will it have performance impact

Comment: " with every function executed inside the memory used by the daemon process grows" : looks like you have a memory leak in one of your modules...

Comment: lets say daemon loop runs two functions,'a' and 'b'. If 'a' takes 20 MB and 'b' takes 25 MB.. then daemon grows as 20 MB -> 45MB
The memeory of func 'a' and 'b' is not freed because parent process is still running